# PHP + Wordpress - get a list of files from a directory

Tags: php, wordpress, file, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get files from a dir filtered by certain extension in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541180/best-way-to-get-files-from-a-dir-filtered-by-certain-extension-in-php)

Are there any native WP functions that are able to list files based by extension from a directory?
if not, how do I do this with php?

I want to get the file names of all .css files from a certain folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about wordpress

But in PHP, you want the glob command - http://php.net/glob

Comment: thanks, but I get the server file path. is there any way I can get only the short file name?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`glob`](http://www.php.net/glob) like so:

```
$file_paths = glob('/path/to/files/*.extension');
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [glob](https://www.php.net/glob) function

```
$files=glob("/path/to/your/folder/*.css");
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo "$file<br>";
}
```